# How to differentiate themes and styles?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-styles

I know that themes and styles in android are different things, with different directives.

Appcompat library has a few `<style>` declarations for `CardView`: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/cardview/res/values/styles.xml

Is it style or theme? What is the coreect way to use it: `style="@style/CardView.Light"` or `android:theme="@style/CardView.Light"`

Comment: refer https://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/